# Stripe checkout - capture onclick event of 'Pay by card' button

Tags: javascript, checkout

I am using the Stripe Javascript checkout library. I have multiple instances of the checkout button on my page, I need to capture the onclick event of the buttons so that I can dynamically add a hidden field to the checkout form before the overlay comes up.

Is there anyway to capture the onclick event of the button, and if so to tell which of the buttons was clicked?

Edited to include code below. Note: this is the provided code from Stripe.

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_MhUiNzdsSkIvzW5Mpwikw38Z"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: There's definitely a way to capture the onclick event. How are you implementing the code? If you read the docs it shows you how to implement a custom button with a click handler https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: It is definitely possible using the custom integration but I am hoping to not have to use the custom and to just use the standard checkout 'Pay by card' button.

Comment: The Stripe docs say "When a user clicks the button and completes payment, we will submit your form with a stripeToken along with any other <input>s in your form". Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what you can do. Looks like Stripe is listening for the form submit event, so what you can do is add a click event listener to the button

HTML

```
<form id="btn1" action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_MhUiNzdsSkIvzW5Mpwikw38Z"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1 button');
btn1.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // do stuff for btn1 click
});
```

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of this. Excellent, thank you.